# Need to delete beta in-app download data from play store account

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, beta

I'm developing an Android app that's in beta that downloads music tracks from a separate server.  To ensure that the app's purchase functionality is working correctly, I need to rescind the purchases (not just refund from the Dev Console), but the Play Store holds this locked up somehow so that I can't reverse Google Play's record of the purchase.  So... my app can't return to the "haven't purchased" state.  I've look everywhere for an answer to this.  I can't believe that it's not a common issue, or maybe I don't know what exactly to search for.
TIA

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].